# ADF - Dynamic Sheet

Tags: azure

i am trying to Append Datasets from Excel files on ADF. In one file my tab name is "CD" and in other it is "LD". I have several files like this with various tab names and same data format that need to be Appended in a single table. How can i do this dynamically on ADF?

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

1. make an excel sheet having names of all the source data sheet names.
2. use a lookup activity to fetch all the names of source data from this sheet.
3. Parameterize your dataset and use the output of lookup activity as parameters.
4. Use a forEach activity and use copy activity inside it for copying your data